# regular expression not recognized by django

Tags: django, django-views, django-2.1

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to create a simple path to later link it to the database, for now: I created this URL path in my music app:

```
urlpatterns = [
# /music/
path('', views.index, name='index'),

# /music/*****/
path(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

And I added this to the views.py:

```
def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Album id: " + str(album_id) + "</h2>")
```

But it doesn't work, every time I ask for this url: http://localhost:8000/music/2 I got "Page not found"

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `path(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),` This line is not correct. Either user re_path or url. The better option is `path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use django path converts for your use case. So, please 
change

```
path(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

to

```
path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Reference: https://learnbatta.com/blog/custom-path-converters-in-django-17/